# How to convert the social book search XML collection into TREC collection?

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am using Terrier IR platform for my experiments with Social Book Search dataset containing 2.8 million XML documents, each having more than 67 metadata fields. A sample XML file is given bellow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- version 1.0 / 2009-11-06T15:56:12+01:00 -->
<!DOCTYPE book SYSTEM "books.dtd">
<book>
<isbn>0373078005</isbn>
<title>Never Trust A Lady (Silhouette Intimate Moments, No 800) (Harlequin Intimate Moments, No 800)</title>
<ean>9780373078004</ean>
<binding>Paperback</binding>
<label>Silhouette</label>
<browseNode id="388186011">Refinements</browseNode>
<browseNode id="394174011">Binding (binding)</browseNode>
<browseNode id="400272011">Paperback</browseNode>
</browseNodes>
</book>
```

However, before indexing, I want to convert the collection into TREC collection format. All the XML files within a specific folder should be converted into a single TREC file, a sample is shown below:

```
<book>
<isbn>0373078005</isbn>
<text>0373078005 Never Trust A Lady (Silhouette Intimate Moments, No 800 (Harlequin Intimate Moments, No 800) 9780373078004 Paperback Silhouette $3.99 Silhouette Silhouette 1997-07-01 Silhouette Refinements Binding (binding) Paperback </text>
</book>
<book>
<isbn>0373084005</isbn>
<text>0373084005 Written On The Wind (Silhouette Romance, No 400) 9780373084005 Paperback Silhouette $1.95 Silhouette Silhouette 1985-11-01 Silhouette 70 420 650 10 Rita Rainville Author Artificial intellingence Romance contemporary sr category Romance Subjects Contemporary Series Silhouette Romance Books General Refinements Binding (binding) Paperback Format (feature_browse-bin) Printed Books General AAS</text>
</book>
...
```

I created `C:\xmlfiles\python-trec` and created two folders in it namely, `data1` and `data2` and put some xml files in both folders. I used a python script available at: http:lab.hypotheses.org/1129, which I modified as bellow:

```
import os, sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
datadest="no collection path"
datdir = "C:\\xmlfiles\\python-trec\\"
for folds in os.listdir(datdir):
    os.mkdir(datadest+folds)
    trectxt=""
    for files in os.listdir(datdir+folds):
        if files.endswith(".xml"):
            content= open(datdir+"/"+folds+"/"+files,'r').read()
            soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
            texts = soup.findAll("book")
            for text in texts:
                isbn =texts[0].findAll("isbn")[0].getText()
                trectxt+="<book>\n<isbn>"+isbn+"</isbn>\n"
                trectxt+="<text>"+' '.join(texts[0].findAll(text=True))+"</text>\n</book>\n"
                f=open(datadest+folds+"/"+folds+".xml","w")
                f.write(trectxt)
                f.close()
```

I get the following error message:

```
C:\Python27>python C:\Python27\Scripts\trec-conversion.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\trec-conversion.py", line 6, in <module>
   os.mkdir(datadest+folds)
 WindowsError: [Error 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: 'no collection pathdata1'
```

After modifying the line: `datadest="no collection path"` to `datadest="C:\\xmlfiles\\python-trec\\"` , I got the following error message:

```
C:\Python27>python C:\Python27\Scripts\trec-conversion.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\trec-conversion.py", line 6, in <module>
   os.mkdir(datadest+folds)
WindowsError: [Error 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: 'C:\\xmlfiles\\python-trec\\data1'
```

Then, I created a new folder `C:\\xmlfiles\\python-trec\\python-trec-results` and modified the line : `datadest="no collection path"` to `datadest="C:\\xmlfiles\\python-trec\\python-trec-results"` , I got the following error message:

```
C:\Python27\Scripts\trec-conversion.py:11: UserWarning: No parser was explicitly specified, so I'm using the best available HTML parser for this system ("html.parser"). This usually isn't a problem, but if you run this code on another system, or in a different virtual environment, it may use a different parser and behave differently.

The code that caused this warning is on line 11 of the file 
C:\Python27\Scripts\trec-conversion.py. To get rid of this warning, pass the additional argument 'features="html.parser"' to the BeautifulSoup constructor.

soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\Scripts\trec-conversion.py", line 18, in <module>
    f.write(trectxt)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 1141: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The code generates the required TREC file for data1 folder but fails to produce the same for data2 folder with the above message.

Please help

--Rocky

Answer (score 0):

I made the following changes:

```
# encoding=utf8
import os, sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

datadest="C:\\xmlfiles\\python-trec-results\\"
datdir = "C:\\xmlfiles\\python-trec\\"

for folds in os.listdir(datdir):
    os.mkdir(datadest+folds)
    trectxt=""
    for files in os.listdir(datdir+folds):
        if files.endswith(".xml"):
            content= open(datdir+"/"+folds+"/"+files,'r').read()
            soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml', from_encoding='utf-8')
            texts = soup.findAll("book")
            for text in texts:
                isbn =texts[0].findAll("isbn")[0].getText()
                trectxt+="<book>\n<isbn>"+isbn+"</isbn>\n"
                trectxt+="<text>"+' '.join(texts[0].findAll(text=True))+"</text>\n</book>\n"
                f=open(datadest+folds+"/"+folds+".xml","w")
                f.write(trectxt)
                f.close()
```

and the program works now!
However, it gives too much extra white spaces inside the value of the  and  nodes, as can be seen bellow:

```
<book>
<isbn>0268020000</isbn>
<text>
0268020000 
Aquinas On Matter and Form and the Elements: A Translation and Interpretation of the DE PRINCIPIIS NATURAE and the DE MIXTIONE ELEMENTORUM of St. Thomas Aquinas 
9780268020002 
Paperback 
University of Notre Dame Press 
$25.00 
University of Notre Dame Press 
University of Notre Dame Press 


1998-03-28 
University of Notre Dame Press 

2000-11-16 
Wonderful Exposition 
Bobick has done it again.  After reading Bobick's insightful translation and exposition of Aquinas' "De Ente et Esentia", I was pleased to find that his knack for explaining Aquinas' complex ideas in metaphysics and natural philospohy is repeated in this book.  For those who wish to understand Aquinas in depth, this book is a must. 
5 
0 
0 

Physics 
Cosmology 
Professional & Technical 



</text>
</book>
<book>
<isbn>0268037000</isbn>
<text>
0268037000
...
```

I want to remove the unnecessary whitespaces and returns to make it look like the following:

```
<book>
<isbn>0268020000</isbn>
<text> ....text goes here....</text>
</book>
<book>
<isbn> 0268037000 </isbn>
<text>....text goes here.....</text>
</book>
...
```

I have tried the available answers on removing white spaces, but they don't work for me...
Please help.